# running Ruby On Rails project using mysql db shows error on first run

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have Ruby version 1.9.3p125 and Rails version 3.2.1. I used the installer from railsinstaller.org, I installed MySQL from its official website.

updated gem using      gem update --system
gem version is 1.8.24

I did following tasks

```
$ gem install mysql
$ gem install mysql2
```

all that i did, was without any problems. I'm using 64 bit Win-7

I created new project without any error

```
C:\Sites> rails new mytestsite -d mysql
```

I copied the libmysql.dll to the Ruby bin folder

and now

```
C:\Sites\mytestsite> rails s
```

shows this problem as shown in image

Please Help, I cant Move further!

[image]

Comment: take a look in the file mentioned on the first line of the error. See what is require-d in its second line and take a look at its 193-th line.

Comment: Did you try rake db:setup first?

Answer (score 0):

You get a load error when rails tries to connect to your SQL database. So you probbably did not create the needed database. in your database configuration file there should be a name for the database, and a username and password that rails is going to use to connect with. Make sure to create the database in your SQL database.

```
CREATE DATABASE databasename
```

then make sure the user that rails is using to connect with exists.

```
CREATE USER username@localhost
```

Then grant the user permissions to read and write in the new database

```
grant usage on *.databasename to username@localhost identified by 'password';
```

after doing this your rails should be able to connect to your mysql